# python 3 - how to keep "\" from command line argument as raw string

Tags: python, python-3.x, escaping

Code is very simple:

```
import sys
for arg in sys.argv:
    print(arg)
```

When I run it using:

```
myProgram.py \\
```

It prints:

```
C:\myProgram.py
\\
```

Since "\" is special, under the hood, python addes extra "\"s so the inputed "\\" becomes "\\\\", and when it prints it becames to "\\" again. How can I stop this, or delete the extra "\"s added by python? So when the inputed argument is "\\", it prints "\"; and when the inputed argument is "\t", it prints a [tab]; "\n" to print a new line; etc?

My search leads me to try the "raw string", so I changed my code to

```
import sys
for arg in sys.argv:
    arg.replace(r'\\',r'\')
    print(arg)
```

But it throws error saying

```
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal
```

Seems the "raw string" is not working here?

UPDATE: Screenshot with slight change

[image: program]

[image: output]

Comment: Cannot duplicate the original problem. And raw strings won't help you. Are you sure cmd.exe needs 2 backslashes to generate 1?

Comment: [Cannot reproduce](http://ideone.com/FeSzcz). If you're running on Windows, I suspect that `\\` is literally just `\\`, so Python is doing the right thing.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Thanks for comments! May I ask what's the result you get? I was saying, in Windows cmd.exe, 2 backslashes in the argumet will generate 2 backslashes in the output. I wish, or am trying to make, 2 backslashes to generate 1. I also added screenshots, hoping to make myself clear.

Comment: @WaleedKhan Thanks for the comment. The two backslashes needs to be passed in as command line argument.

Comment: May I ask why you're after this?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Well, this is related to a project I am working on. A bug is boiled down to this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to evaluate argument as string, so you can use `eval`

```
import sys
for arg in sys.argv:
    print(eval('"' + arg.replace('"', '\\"') + '"'))
```

**WARNING:** you should not use this approach in production, because [Eval really is dangerous](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html)

Comment: This actually works! Although I have no idea about the arg.replace(). There is no quotation mark in the argument string to be replaced, isn't it?

Comment: You need to understand difference between `'\n'`, `'\\n'`, `r'\n'` and `r'\\n'`. The best way is to open python interpreter and just type some constants and try `str`, `repr` and `print` on them. Also, try to replace `print(arg)` with `print(repr(arg))`, to see what you actually get in `sys.argv`

Answer (score 1):

I think that this problem is explained in [this FAQ](http://docs.python.org/2/faq/design.html#why-can-t-raw-strings-r-strings-end-with-a-backslash)

Comment: Thanks! This explains the error, but the problem is still there.